# Using boolean logic on time (javascript)

Tags: javascript, boolean-logic

Javascript has built-in function for time where

```
    var date = new Date();
    d.getHours() //gets the hour in integer 0-23
    d.getMinutes() //gets the minute in integer 0-59
```

I would like function (e.g. `A()`) to run between 0:35 and 4:35

Is this possible to do using just simple logic operation (`&&`, `||`)?
I don't think it is possible, but I wanted to know the elegant way to implement it.

Comment: You want to iterate on time values? Or you want your function to run between those two times of the day continuously? Please clarify.

Comment: It won't run on its own, you could make a function `A()` run **if the time was** between **x** and **y**.

Comment: @bažmegakapa: the latter is what I am looking for. () will handle polling so there is no need worry.

Comment: @gideon: yes that is what I was looking for. A() will handle polling so there is no need worry.

Comment: The answers below are all good. I am surprised to see some of the implementations that I would never have thought of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically it's possible, but you are absolutely right in that this is not an elegant solution:

```
var h = d.getHours();
var m = d.getMinutes();
if ((h == 0 && m >= 35) || (h > 0 && h < 4) || (h == 4 && m <=35)) {
    A();
}
```

Comment: @aaronfrost I don't think so.

Answer (score 2):

```
var date = Date.now();     // ES5 - or new Date().getTime()
var sec = (date / 1000);   // seconds since epoch
sec = sec % 86400;         // seconds since midnight
var mins = sec / 60;       // minutes since midnight

if (mins >= 35 && mins < 4*60+35) {
    A();
}
```

Comment: does not work. Other then secs->sec error, also dividing by 60 does not give the minutes. Maybe I am wrong, but I did play around with it for 10 minutes...

Comment: @Prometheus sorry - there were _two_ `sec` vs `secs` typos...  The code above is now correct.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the timestamp to compare.

```
var date = new Date();
var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = date.getMonth();
var day = date.getDate();
var start = new Date(year, month, day, 0, 35);
var end = new Date(year, month, day, 4, 35);

if (date.getTime() >= start.getTime() && date.getTime() <= end.getTime()) {
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function foo(){
    var now = new Date();
    if( (now.getHours() < 1 && now.getMinutes() < 35) 
       || (now.getHours() > 3 && now.getMinutes() > 35) ){
         return false; //if it isn't in your time, return false
    }

    //put your code here. this will run between the hours of 12:35AM and 4:35AM local time

}
```

I hope this is what you are looking for. If not, let me know.

Comment: At 4:15AM, it would run your code. At 4:15PM, it would return false.

Comment: It doesn't return false at 4:15pm. Basically it runs at x:15 whenever x>=1.

Comment: You are wrong. It only runs between the hours of 0:35 and 4:35. Other than that it returns false. Write a unit test or something. Anything beyond 4:35AM returns false

var a = new Date().setHours(4,35,0,0);
var b = new Date().setHours(4,36,0,0);
foo(a);foo(b);